# Docker not able to install git on Ubuntu container

Tags: git, docker, ubuntu, sudo, apt

I have a Docker image that uses `ubuntu:21.04`. When I SSH onto it I try to install git [using the official Git Ubuntu installation instructions](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git) but I get an error:

```
root@c812b171354a:/home/ubuntu# sudo apt install git-all
bash: sudo: command not found
```

I'm surprised to see `sudo` doesn't exist! So I try it without `sudo`:

```
root@c812b171354a:/home/ubuntu# apt install git-all
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package git-all
```

So I ask: **what command(s) can I run to install `git` on a Dockerized Ubuntu 21.04 container?**

#### Update

Here is my full Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:21.04

COPY keep-alive.sh /home/ubuntu/keep-alive.sh

# give keep-alive script permission to run
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/home/ubuntu/keep-alive.sh"]

# install git
RUN apt update -y
RUN apt install -y gpgv2 git-all

CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/home/ubuntu/keep-alive.sh"]
```

When I build the image:

```
docker build -t myorg/linux-worker .
```

I get:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon   7.68kB
Step 1/6 : FROM ubuntu:21.04
 ---> 478aa0080b60
Step 2/6 : COPY keep-alive.sh /home/ubuntu/keep-alive.sh
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e1bcc0d7dd20
Step 3/6 : RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/home/ubuntu/keep-alive.sh"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ef46c36ec41b
Step 4/6 : RUN apt update -y
 ---> Running in fee517c02852

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security InRelease [101 kB]
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security InRelease
  gpgv, gpgv2 or gpgv1 required for verification, but neither seems installed
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease [269 kB]
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease
  gpgv, gpgv2 or gpgv1 required for verification, but neither seems installed
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates InRelease [109 kB]
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates InRelease
  gpgv, gpgv2 or gpgv1 required for verification, but neither seems installed
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-backports InRelease [90.7 kB]
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-backports InRelease
  gpgv, gpgv2 or gpgv1 required for verification, but neither seems installed
Reading package lists...
W: GPG error: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security InRelease: gpgv, gpgv2 or gpgv1 required for verification, but neither seems installed
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security InRelease' is not signed.
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease: gpgv, gpgv2 or gpgv1 required for verification, but neither seems installed
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' is not signed.
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates InRelease: gpgv, gpgv2 or gpgv1 required for verification, but neither seems installed
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates InRelease' is not signed.
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-backports InRelease: gpgv, gpgv2 or gpgv1 required for verification, but neither seems installed
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-backports InRelease' is not signed.
The command '/bin/sh -c apt update -y' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Are there any other dependencies I need?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Ubuntu image comes with nothing in the package listings, so you need to `apt update` then `apt install git-all`.

Add the `-y` options to those if you put them in `RUN` commands in the Dockerfile.

Comment: Thanks @AdamF (+1) -- please see my edits above and the new errors, any ideas there as well?

Comment: That is strange. I just tested these commands with `docker run -it ubuntu:21.04  bash` and then going straight into the `apt` commands.

Comment: Thanks again, but I'm still getting errors. I edited my question to contain: (1) the entire Dockerfile, (2) my exact build command and (3) the full console output I get after I run the build command.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for as I don't want to create a new image using dockerfile. Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

Add to your docker file:

```
RUN apt update -y --allow-unauthenticated
RUN apt install -y git
```

---

### **Edit**

I created a docker file like yours and tried to run it.

I got NO errors, it worked as expected.

I am on Ubuntu 18.03 and I am using docker 20.10.6.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:21.04

COPY keep-alive.sh /home/ubuntu/keep-alive.sh

# give keep-alive script permission to run
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/home/ubuntu/keep-alive.sh"]

# install git
RUN apt update -y
RUN apt install -y git

CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/home/ubuntu/keep-alive.sh"]
```

**Docker build output**

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon    274MB

Step 1/6 : FROM ubuntu:21.04
 ---> 478aa0080b60
Step 2/6 : COPY keep-alive.sh /home/ubuntu/keep-alive.sh
 ---> 7b475eac1121
Step 3/6 : RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/home/ubuntu/keep-alive.sh"]
 ---> Running in d6ae7c5bc43a
Removing intermediate container d6ae7c5bc43a
 ---> 2c714d7af408
Step 4/6 : RUN apt update -y
 ---> Running in 3b617d125190
[91m
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

[0mGet:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease [269 kB]
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security InRelease [101 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates InRelease [109 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-backports InRelease [90.7 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/universe amd64 Packages [16.8 MB]
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/main amd64 Packages [120 kB]
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [1725 B]
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/restricted amd64 Packages [114 kB]
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/universe amd64 Packages [227 kB]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/multiverse amd64 Packages [252 kB]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/restricted amd64 Packages [111 kB]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages [1791 kB]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [114 kB]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/main amd64 Packages [210 kB]
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [1725 B]
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/universe amd64 Packages [262 kB]
Fetched 20.6 MB in 6s (3301 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
5 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
Removing intermediate container 3b617d125190
 ---> 39d3187756a3
Step 5/6 : RUN apt install -y git
 ---> Running in aafba3605194
[91m
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

[0mReading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following additional packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates git-man krb5-locales less libasn1-8-heimdal libbrotli1
  libbsd0 libcbor0.6 libcurl3-gnutls libedit2 liberror-perl libexpat1
  libfido2-1 libgdbm-compat4 libgdbm6 libgssapi-krb5-2 libgssapi3-heimdal
  libhcrypto4-heimdal libheimbase1-heimdal libheimntlm0-heimdal
  libhx509-5-heimdal libk5crypto3 libkeyutils1 libkrb5-26-heimdal libkrb5-3
  libkrb5support0 libldap-2.4-2 libldap-common libmd0 libnghttp2-14
  libperl5.32 libpsl5 libroken18-heimdal librtmp1 libsasl2-2 libsasl2-modules
  libsasl2-modules-db libsqlite3-0 libssh-4 libssl1.1 libwind0-heimdal
  libx11-6 libx11-data libxau6 libxcb1 libxdmcp6 libxext6 libxmuu1 netbase
  openssh-client openssl patch perl perl-modules-5.32 publicsuffix xauth
Suggested packages:
  gettext-base git-daemon-run | git-daemon-sysvinit git-doc git-el git-email
  git-gui gitk gitweb git-cvs git-mediawiki git-svn gdbm-l10n krb5-doc
  krb5-user libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit | libsasl2-modules-gssapi-heimdal
  libsasl2-modules-ldap libsasl2-modules-otp libsasl2-modules-sql keychain
  libpam-ssh monkeysphere ssh-askpass ed diffutils-doc perl-doc
  libterm-readline-gnu-perl | libterm-readline-perl-perl make
  libtap-harness-archive-perl
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates git git-man krb5-locales less libasn1-8-heimdal libbrotli1
  libbsd0 libcbor0.6 libcurl3-gnutls libedit2 liberror-perl libexpat1
  libfido2-1 libgdbm-compat4 libgdbm6 libgssapi-krb5-2 libgssapi3-heimdal
  libhcrypto4-heimdal libheimbase1-heimdal libheimntlm0-heimdal
  libhx509-5-heimdal libk5crypto3 libkeyutils1 libkrb5-26-heimdal libkrb5-3
  libkrb5support0 libldap-2.4-2 libldap-common libmd0 libnghttp2-14
  libperl5.32 libpsl5 libroken18-heimdal librtmp1 libsasl2-2 libsasl2-modules
  libsasl2-modules-db libsqlite3-0 libssh-4 libssl1.1 libwind0-heimdal
  libx11-6 libx11-data libxau6 libxcb1 libxdmcp6 libxext6 libxmuu1 netbase
  openssh-client openssl patch perl perl-modules-5.32 publicsuffix xauth
0 upgraded, 57 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
Need to get 18.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 103 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 perl-modules-5.32 all 5.32.1-3ubuntu2 [2755 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libgdbm6 amd64 1.19-2 [27.5 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libgdbm-compat4 amd64 1.19-2 [6236 B]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libperl5.32 amd64 5.32.1-3ubuntu2 [4047 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 perl amd64 5.32.1-3ubuntu2 [225 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libssl1.1 amd64 1.1.1j-1ubuntu3 [1324 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 openssl amd64 1.1.1j-1ubuntu3 [625 kB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 ca-certificates all 20210119build1 [147 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 krb5-locales all 1.18.3-4 [11.3 kB]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 less amd64 551-2 [123 kB]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libmd0 amd64 1.0.3-3build1 [21.5 kB]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libbsd0 amd64 0.11.3-1ubuntu2 [41.1 kB]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libexpat1 amd64 2.2.10-2 [76.2 kB]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libkrb5support0 amd64 1.18.3-4 [30.8 kB]
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libk5crypto3 amd64 1.18.3-4 [77.9 kB]
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libkeyutils1 amd64 1.6.1-2ubuntu1 [10.1 kB]
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libkrb5-3 amd64 1.18.3-4 [326 kB]
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libgssapi-krb5-2 amd64 1.18.3-4 [129 kB]
Get:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libsqlite3-0 amd64 3.34.1-3 [588 kB]
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 netbase all 6.2 [13.0 kB]
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libcbor0.6 amd64 0.6.0-0ubuntu3 [21.7 kB]
Get:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libedit2 amd64 3.1-20191231-2 [87.8 kB]
Get:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libfido2-1 amd64 1.6.0-2 [53.4 kB]
Get:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libpsl5 amd64 0.21.0-1.2 [53.5 kB]
Get:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libxau6 amd64 1:1.0.9-1build3 [7360 B]
Get:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libxdmcp6 amd64 1:1.1.3-0ubuntu3 [10.3 kB]
Get:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libxcb1 amd64 1.14-3ubuntu1 [45.3 kB]
Get:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/main amd64 libx11-data all 2:1.7.0-2ubuntu0.1 [112 kB]
Get:29 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/main amd64 libx11-6 amd64 2:1.7.0-2ubuntu0.1 [577 kB]
Get:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libxext6 amd64 2:1.3.4-0ubuntu3 [28.9 kB]
Get:31 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libxmuu1 amd64 2:1.1.3-0ubuntu1 [9728 B]
Get:32 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 openssh-client amd64 1:8.4p1-5ubuntu1 [705 kB]
Get:33 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 publicsuffix all 20210108.1309-1 [116 kB]
Get:34 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 xauth amd64 1:1.1-1 [24.8 kB]
Get:35 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libbrotli1 amd64 1.0.9-2build2 [274 kB]
Get:36 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libroken18-heimdal amd64 7.7.0+dfsg-2 [41.8 kB]
Get:37 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libasn1-8-heimdal amd64 7.7.0+dfsg-2 [181 kB]
Get:38 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libheimbase1-heimdal amd64 7.7.0+dfsg-2 [29.7 kB]
Get:39 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libhcrypto4-heimdal amd64 7.7.0+dfsg-2 [88.0 kB]
Get:40 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libwind0-heimdal amd64 7.7.0+dfsg-2 [47.6 kB]
Get:41 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libhx509-5-heimdal amd64 7.7.0+dfsg-2 [107 kB]
Get:42 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libkrb5-26-heimdal amd64 7.7.0+dfsg-2 [207 kB]
Get:43 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libheimntlm0-heimdal amd64 7.7.0+dfsg-2 [15.1 kB]
Get:44 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libgssapi3-heimdal amd64 7.7.0+dfsg-2 [96.5 kB]
Get:45 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libsasl2-modules-db amd64 2.1.27+dfsg-2ubuntu1 [14.7 kB]
Get:46 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libsasl2-2 amd64 2.1.27+dfsg-2ubuntu1 [49.3 kB]
Get:47 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libldap-2.4-2 amd64 2.4.57+dfsg-2ubuntu1 [156 kB]
Get:48 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libnghttp2-14 amd64 1.43.0-1 [72.5 kB]
Get:49 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 librtmp1 amd64 2.4+20151223.gitfa8646d.1-2build2 [55.0 kB]
Get:50 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libssh-4 amd64 0.9.5-1 [172 kB]
Get:51 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libcurl3-gnutls amd64 7.74.0-1ubuntu2 [247 kB]
Get:52 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 liberror-perl all 0.17029-1 [26.5 kB]
Get:53 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 git-man all 1:2.30.2-1ubuntu1 [931 kB]
Get:54 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 git amd64 1:2.30.2-1ubuntu1 [3457 kB]
Get:55 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libldap-common all 2.4.57+dfsg-2ubuntu1 [16.4 kB]
Get:56 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libsasl2-modules amd64 2.1.27+dfsg-2ubuntu1 [48.8 kB]
Get:57 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 patch amd64 2.7.6-7 [105 kB]
[91mdebconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
[0mFetched 18.9 MB in 6s (3386 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package perl-modules-5.32.
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 4273 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-perl-modules-5.32_5.32.1-3ubuntu2_all.deb ...
Unpacking perl-modules-5.32 (5.32.1-3ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgdbm6:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../01-libgdbm6_1.19-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgdbm6:amd64 (1.19-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgdbm-compat4:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../02-libgdbm-compat4_1.19-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgdbm-compat4:amd64 (1.19-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libperl5.32:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../03-libperl5.32_5.32.1-3ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libperl5.32:amd64 (5.32.1-3ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package perl.
Preparing to unpack .../04-perl_5.32.1-3ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking perl (5.32.1-3ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libssl1.1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../05-libssl1.1_1.1.1j-1ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libssl1.1:amd64 (1.1.1j-1ubuntu3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package openssl.
Preparing to unpack .../06-openssl_1.1.1j-1ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking openssl (1.1.1j-1ubuntu3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package ca-certificates.
Preparing to unpack .../07-ca-certificates_20210119build1_all.deb ...
Unpacking ca-certificates (20210119build1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package krb5-locales.
Preparing to unpack .../08-krb5-locales_1.18.3-4_all.deb ...
Unpacking krb5-locales (1.18.3-4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package less.
Preparing to unpack .../09-less_551-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking less (551-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libmd0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../10-libmd0_1.0.3-3build1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libmd0:amd64 (1.0.3-3build1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libbsd0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../11-libbsd0_0.11.3-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libbsd0:amd64 (0.11.3-1ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libexpat1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../12-libexpat1_2.2.10-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libexpat1:amd64 (2.2.10-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libkrb5support0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../13-libkrb5support0_1.18.3-4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libkrb5support0:amd64 (1.18.3-4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libk5crypto3:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../14-libk5crypto3_1.18.3-4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libk5crypto3:amd64 (1.18.3-4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libkeyutils1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../15-libkeyutils1_1.6.1-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libkeyutils1:amd64 (1.6.1-2ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libkrb5-3:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../16-libkrb5-3_1.18.3-4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libkrb5-3:amd64 (1.18.3-4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgssapi-krb5-2:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../17-libgssapi-krb5-2_1.18.3-4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgssapi-krb5-2:amd64 (1.18.3-4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libsqlite3-0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../18-libsqlite3-0_3.34.1-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libsqlite3-0:amd64 (3.34.1-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package netbase.
Preparing to unpack .../19-netbase_6.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking netbase (6.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libcbor0.6:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../20-libcbor0.6_0.6.0-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcbor0.6:amd64 (0.6.0-0ubuntu3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libedit2:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../21-libedit2_3.1-20191231-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libedit2:amd64 (3.1-20191231-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libfido2-1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../22-libfido2-1_1.6.0-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libfido2-1:amd64 (1.6.0-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpsl5:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../23-libpsl5_0.21.0-1.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpsl5:amd64 (0.21.0-1.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libxau6:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../24-libxau6_1%3a1.0.9-1build3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxau6:amd64 (1:1.0.9-1build3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libxdmcp6:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../25-libxdmcp6_1%3a1.1.3-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxdmcp6:amd64 (1:1.1.3-0ubuntu3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libxcb1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../26-libxcb1_1.14-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxcb1:amd64 (1.14-3ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libx11-data.
Preparing to unpack .../27-libx11-data_2%3a1.7.0-2ubuntu0.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libx11-data (2:1.7.0-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libx11-6:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../28-libx11-6_2%3a1.7.0-2ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libx11-6:amd64 (2:1.7.0-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libxext6:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../29-libxext6_2%3a1.3.4-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxext6:amd64 (2:1.3.4-0ubuntu3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libxmuu1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../30-libxmuu1_2%3a1.1.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxmuu1:amd64 (2:1.1.3-0ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package openssh-client.
Preparing to unpack .../31-openssh-client_1%3a8.4p1-5ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking openssh-client (1:8.4p1-5ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package publicsuffix.
Preparing to unpack .../32-publicsuffix_20210108.1309-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking publicsuffix (20210108.1309-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package xauth.
Preparing to unpack .../33-xauth_1%3a1.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking xauth (1:1.1-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libbrotli1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../34-libbrotli1_1.0.9-2build2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libbrotli1:amd64 (1.0.9-2build2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libroken18-heimdal:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../35-libroken18-heimdal_7.7.0+dfsg-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libroken18-heimdal:amd64 (7.7.0+dfsg-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libasn1-8-heimdal:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../36-libasn1-8-heimdal_7.7.0+dfsg-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libasn1-8-heimdal:amd64 (7.7.0+dfsg-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libheimbase1-heimdal:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../37-libheimbase1-heimdal_7.7.0+dfsg-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libheimbase1-heimdal:amd64 (7.7.0+dfsg-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libhcrypto4-heimdal:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../38-libhcrypto4-heimdal_7.7.0+dfsg-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libhcrypto4-heimdal:amd64 (7.7.0+dfsg-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libwind0-heimdal:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../39-libwind0-heimdal_7.7.0+dfsg-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libwind0-heimdal:amd64 (7.7.0+dfsg-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libhx509-5-heimdal:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../40-libhx509-5-heimdal_7.7.0+dfsg-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libhx509-5-heimdal:amd64 (7.7.0+dfsg-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libkrb5-26-heimdal:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../41-libkrb5-26-heimdal_7.7.0+dfsg-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libkrb5-26-heimdal:amd64 (7.7.0+dfsg-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libheimntlm0-heimdal:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../42-libheimntlm0-heimdal_7.7.0+dfsg-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libheimntlm0-heimdal:amd64 (7.7.0+dfsg-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgssapi3-heimdal:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../43-libgssapi3-heimdal_7.7.0+dfsg-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgssapi3-heimdal:amd64 (7.7.0+dfsg-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libsasl2-modules-db:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../44-libsasl2-modules-db_2.1.27+dfsg-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libsasl2-modules-db:amd64 (2.1.27+dfsg-2ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libsasl2-2:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../45-libsasl2-2_2.1.27+dfsg-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libsasl2-2:amd64 (2.1.27+dfsg-2ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libldap-2.4-2:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../46-libldap-2.4-2_2.4.57+dfsg-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libldap-2.4-2:amd64 (2.4.57+dfsg-2ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnghttp2-14:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../47-libnghttp2-14_1.43.0-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnghttp2-14:amd64 (1.43.0-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package librtmp1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../48-librtmp1_2.4+20151223.gitfa8646d.1-2build2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking librtmp1:amd64 (2.4+20151223.gitfa8646d.1-2build2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libssh-4:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../49-libssh-4_0.9.5-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libssh-4:amd64 (0.9.5-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libcurl3-gnutls:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../50-libcurl3-gnutls_7.74.0-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 (7.74.0-1ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package liberror-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../51-liberror-perl_0.17029-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking liberror-perl (0.17029-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package git-man.
Preparing to unpack .../52-git-man_1%3a2.30.2-1ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking git-man (1:2.30.2-1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package git.
Preparing to unpack .../53-git_1%3a2.30.2-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking git (1:2.30.2-1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libldap-common.
Preparing to unpack .../54-libldap-common_2.4.57+dfsg-2ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libldap-common (2.4.57+dfsg-2ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libsasl2-modules:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../55-libsasl2-modules_2.1.27+dfsg-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libsasl2-modules:amd64 (2.1.27+dfsg-2ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package patch.
Preparing to unpack .../56-patch_2.7.6-7_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking patch (2.7.6-7) ...
Setting up libexpat1:amd64 (2.2.10-2) ...
Setting up libxau6:amd64 (1:1.0.9-1build3) ...
Setting up libkeyutils1:amd64 (1.6.1-2ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libpsl5:amd64 (0.21.0-1.2) ...
Setting up libssl1.1:amd64 (1.1.1j-1ubuntu3) ...
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (TERM is not set, so the dialog frontend is not usable.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
Setting up perl-modules-5.32 (5.32.1-3ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libbrotli1:amd64 (1.0.9-2build2) ...
Setting up libsqlite3-0:amd64 (3.34.1-3) ...
Setting up libsasl2-modules:amd64 (2.1.27+dfsg-2ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libnghttp2-14:amd64 (1.43.0-1) ...
Setting up less (551-2) ...
Setting up krb5-locales (1.18.3-4) ...
Setting up libcbor0.6:amd64 (0.6.0-0ubuntu3) ...
Setting up libldap-common (2.4.57+dfsg-2ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libkrb5support0:amd64 (1.18.3-4) ...
Setting up libsasl2-modules-db:amd64 (2.1.27+dfsg-2ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libx11-data (2:1.7.0-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up librtmp1:amd64 (2.4+20151223.gitfa8646d.1-2build2) ...
Setting up patch (2.7.6-7) ...
Setting up libk5crypto3:amd64 (1.18.3-4) ...
Setting up libsasl2-2:amd64 (2.1.27+dfsg-2ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libroken18-heimdal:amd64 (7.7.0+dfsg-2) ...
Setting up libmd0:amd64 (1.0.3-3build1) ...
Setting up git-man (1:2.30.2-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up netbase (6.2) ...
Setting up libkrb5-3:amd64 (1.18.3-4) ...
Setting up libfido2-1:amd64 (1.6.0-2) ...
Setting up openssl (1.1.1j-1ubuntu3) ...
Setting up libbsd0:amd64 (0.11.3-1ubuntu2) ...
Setting up publicsuffix (20210108.1309-1) ...
Setting up libheimbase1-heimdal:amd64 (7.7.0+dfsg-2) ...
Setting up libgdbm6:amd64 (1.19-2) ...
Setting up libxdmcp6:amd64 (1:1.1.3-0ubuntu3) ...
Setting up libxcb1:amd64 (1.14-3ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libasn1-8-heimdal:amd64 (7.7.0+dfsg-2) ...
Setting up libedit2:amd64 (3.1-20191231-2) ...
Setting up libhcrypto4-heimdal:amd64 (7.7.0+dfsg-2) ...
Setting up ca-certificates (20210119build1) ...
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (TERM is not set, so the dialog frontend is not usable.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
129 added, 0 removed; done.
Setting up libwind0-heimdal:amd64 (7.7.0+dfsg-2) ...
Setting up libgssapi-krb5-2:amd64 (1.18.3-4) ...
Setting up libgdbm-compat4:amd64 (1.19-2) ...
Setting up libperl5.32:amd64 (5.32.1-3ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libssh-4:amd64 (0.9.5-1) ...
Setting up libx11-6:amd64 (2:1.7.0-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libxmuu1:amd64 (2:1.1.3-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up openssh-client (1:8.4p1-5ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libhx509-5-heimdal:amd64 (7.7.0+dfsg-2) ...
Setting up libxext6:amd64 (2:1.3.4-0ubuntu3) ...
Setting up perl (5.32.1-3ubuntu2) ...
Setting up xauth (1:1.1-1) ...
Setting up libkrb5-26-heimdal:amd64 (7.7.0+dfsg-2) ...
Setting up libheimntlm0-heimdal:amd64 (7.7.0+dfsg-2) ...
Setting up liberror-perl (0.17029-1) ...
Setting up libgssapi3-heimdal:amd64 (7.7.0+dfsg-2) ...
Setting up libldap-2.4-2:amd64 (2.4.57+dfsg-2ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 (7.74.0-1ubuntu2) ...
Setting up git (1:2.30.2-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.33-0ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for ca-certificates (20210119build1) ...
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
0 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...
done.
Removing intermediate container aafba3605194
 ---> ae0af91a0d8f
Step 6/6 : CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/home/ubuntu/keep-alive.sh"]
 ---> Running in 9f3b92f01a11
Removing intermediate container 9f3b92f01a11
 ---> fd42e9e244f6
Successfully built fd42e9e244f6
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Antonio (+1) -- please see my edits above and the new errors, any ideas there as well?

Comment: I edited my post adding `gpgv2`. Please try again...

Comment: Thanks again, but I'm still getting errors. I edited my question to contain: (1) the entire Dockerfile, (2) my exact build command and (3) the full console output I get after I run the build command.

Comment: Interesting! Any idea why you need `--allow-unauthenticated` in the RUN command but not when I run apt interactively in the shell?

Comment: Thanks again but now the error is `The command '/bin/sh -c apt update -y --allow-unauthenticated' returned a non-zero code: 100`

Comment: My host is a Mac, I'm wondering if that has anything to do with it?

Comment: i'm having a similar problem running on mac, but it does not matter which package i install, when i run apt-get update on the latest version of the ubuntu image (does not matter the version, 16,18,20...) i get this error. Funny thing is that i had another mac with an older image of ubuntu locally and i did not get any error. Then i tried to delete the ubuntu image and download a fresh one with the latest release, only then i got the error. I don't know if it is something wrong with docker for mac, or something wrong with the apt-get repositories. Did you solve your problem?

Comment: I also want to mention that ubuntu updated all their images 3 days ago, I don't know if there is something related...